# customer balance scale as the exponent of it's currency 

Tags: java, hibernate, bigdecimal, rounding

i have 2 classes under java hibernate project

currency class with variable (exponent) with (BigDecimal) DataType

&

customer class with variable (balance) with (BigDecimal) DataType

i want to set scale of balance as exponent

**example:**

```
1) if exponent = 2, and balance = 230.1340098 then balance must be 230.13
2) if exponent = 1, and balance = 230.1340098 then balance must be 230.1
3) if exponent = 3, and balance = 230.1340098 then balance must be 230.134
4) if exponent = 0, and balance = 230.1340098 then balance must be 230
....
....
....
```

how can i do this?

what's i mean i want to put the customer balance scale as the exponent of his currency

**Note:** i try BigDecimal.setScale() but this method required constant integer field  dataType where exponent is BigDecimal and variable

Comment: Just a side note: if `exponent` is actually an integer, why do you store it as `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigDecimal#setScale(...)` should work:

```
BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(  230.1340098 );  
BigDecimal exponent = new BigDecimal( 2 ) ; //randomly chosen
BigDecimal rounded = balance.setScale( exponent.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP ) ); //you can use another rounding mode
```

This yields `rounded = 230.13`.

Comment: what's i mean i want to put the customer balance scale as the exponent of it's currency

Answer (score 1):

You should extract the integer-value from the exponent-BigDecimal and use that as parameter to setScale. Be aware, that you have to set a RoundingMode:

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("230.1340098");
    BigDecimal exponent;
    exponent = new BigDecimal("0");
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(exponent.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    exponent = new BigDecimal("1");
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(exponent.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    exponent = new BigDecimal("2");
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(exponent.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
    exponent = new BigDecimal("3");
    System.out.println(bd.setScale(exponent.intValue(), RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
```

Comment: i can't declare exponent like that because it is a field in currency hibernate class, what's i mean i want to put the customer balance scale as the exponent of it's currency

Answer (score 0):

You can call `intValue()` on `BigDecimal` to get the desired result.

Code snippet:

```
private void testBigDecimal(BigDecimal exponent, double balance){
    BigDecimal finalOutput = new BigDecimal(balance);
    finalOutput = finalOutput.setScale(exponent.intValue(), BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
    System.out.println(finalOutput.doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: what's i mean i want to put the customer balance scale as the exponent of it's currency

Answer (score 0):

> I try setScale() but this method required constant integer

No, it doesn't require a constant integer. It can accept any integer. You can use BigDecimal.intValue() to get the exponent as the datatype required.

But BigDecimal is a very strange choice of datatype for the exponent value. You can't seriously be expecting it to get beyond the range of an integer.

Comment: what's i mean i want to put the customer balance scale as the exponent of it's currency

Comment: @danny-london You said above the exponent is a `BigDecimal`. It isn't. The scale of a BigDecimal is an integer.

Comment: exponent is a field in currency table that it must be BigDecimal for other use. i know that the scale of a BigDecimal is an integer

Comment: @danny-london The story keeps changing. This is just a design mistake. You only need a range of a couple of dozen for an exponent. *Why* is it a BigInteger?